# Build Model Timeout when importing Gradle project in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, import, gradle, libgdx, gradle-eclipse

I've created a new [libGDX](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/) project, which basically creates a gradle project that you can then import into your respective IDE - I'm using Eclipse Kepler. I import the project by going to file > import > gradle > gradle project. I then point the wizard to the root of my libGDx / gradle project, after which I then get told that I have to "click 'Build Model' before I can select project to import" (no idea why this then doesn't just happen in the background instead of needing a user interaction).

After waiting while I then get the following error message:

> Timeout of 120000 reached waiting for exclusive access to file.....

Just have a look here:

[image]

I ask you, with tears in my eyes, *why*?

**Edit - The error log stack trace:**

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core.util.GradleRunnable.run(GradleRunnable.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
Caused by: org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Timeout of 120000 reached waiting for exclusive access to file: /Users/dean/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-1.11-all/7qd8qq8te5j4f5q9aaei3gh3lj/gradle-1.11-all.zip
    at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core.GradleModelProvider$GroupedModelProvider.ensureModels(GradleModelProvider.java:284)
    at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core.GradleProject.getGradleModel(GradleProject.java:633)
    at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core.GradleProject.getSkeletalGradleModel(GradleProject.java:654)
    at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.ui.wizards.GradleImportWizardPageOne$11.doit(GradleImportWizardPageOne.java:516)
    at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core.util.GradleRunnable.run(GradleRunnable.java:84)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: org.gradle.tooling.GradleConnectionException: Could not install Gradle distribution from 'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.11-all.zip'.
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DistributionFactory$ZippedDistribution.getToolingImplementationClasspath(DistributionFactory.java:112)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.loader.CachingToolingImplementationLoader.create(CachingToolingImplementationLoader.java:36)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.loader.SynchronizedToolingImplementationLoader.create(SynchronizedToolingImplementationLoader.java:40)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.LazyConsumerActionExecutor.onStartAction(LazyConsumerActionExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.LazyConsumerActionExecutor.run(LazyConsumerActionExecutor.java:81)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.run(ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.java:58)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.LoggingInitializerConsumerActionExecutor.run(LoggingInitializerConsumerActionExecutor.java:44)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:55)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.BlockingResultHandler.getResult(BlockingResultHandler.java:46)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultModelBuilder.get(DefaultModelBuilder.java:48)
    at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core.GradleModelProvider.buildModel(GradleModelProvider.java:385)
    at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core.GradleModelProvider$GroupedModelProvider.ensureModels(GradleModelProvider.java:290)
    at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core.GradleProject.getModelProvider(GradleProject.java:569)
    at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core.GradleProject.getGradleModel(GradleProject.java:629)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Timeout of 120000 reached waiting for exclusive access to file: /Users/dean/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-1.11-all/7qd8qq8te5j4f5q9aaei3gh3lj/gradle-1.11-all.zip
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:61)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:44)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DistributionFactory$ZippedDistribution.getToolingImplementationClasspath(DistributionFactory.java:108)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.loader.CachingToolingImplementationLoader.create(CachingToolingImplementationLoader.java:36)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.loader.SynchronizedToolingImplementationLoader.create(SynchronizedToolingImplementationLoader.java:40)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.LazyConsumerActionExecutor.onStartAction(LazyConsumerActionExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.LazyConsumerActionExecutor.run(LazyConsumerActionExecutor.java:81)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.run(ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.java:58)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.LoggingInitializerConsumerActionExecutor.run(LoggingInitializerConsumerActionExecutor.java:44)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:55)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Root exception:
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Timeout of 120000 reached waiting for exclusive access to file: /Users/dean/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-1.11-all/7qd8qq8te5j4f5q9aaei3gh3lj/gradle-1.11-all.zip
    at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core.GradleModelProvider$GroupedModelProvider.ensureModels(GradleModelProvider.java:284)
    at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core.GradleProject.getGradleModel(GradleProject.java:633)
    at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core.GradleProject.getSkeletalGradleModel(GradleProject.java:654)
    at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.ui.wizards.GradleImportWizardPageOne$11.doit(GradleImportWizardPageOne.java:516)
    at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core.util.GradleRunnable.run(GradleRunnable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
Caused by: org.gradle.tooling.GradleConnectionException: Could not install Gradle distribution from 'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.11-all.zip'.
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DistributionFactory$ZippedDistribution.getToolingImplementationClasspath(DistributionFactory.java:112)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.loader.CachingToolingImplementationLoader.create(CachingToolingImplementationLoader.java:36)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.loader.SynchronizedToolingImplementationLoader.create(SynchronizedToolingImplementationLoader.java:40)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.LazyConsumerActionExecutor.onStartAction(LazyConsumerActionExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.LazyConsumerActionExecutor.run(LazyConsumerActionExecutor.java:81)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.run(ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.java:58)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.LoggingInitializerConsumerActionExecutor.run(LoggingInitializerConsumerActionExecutor.java:44)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:55)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.BlockingResultHandler.getResult(BlockingResultHandler.java:46)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultModelBuilder.get(DefaultModelBuilder.java:48)
    at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core.GradleModelProvider.buildModel(GradleModelProvider.java:385)
    at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core.GradleModelProvider$GroupedModelProvider.ensureModels(GradleModelProvider.java:290)
    at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core.GradleProject.getModelProvider(GradleProject.java:569)
    at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core.GradleProject.getGradleModel(GradleProject.java:629)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Timeout of 120000 reached waiting for exclusive access to file: /Users/dean/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-1.11-all/7qd8qq8te5j4f5q9aaei3gh3lj/gradle-1.11-all.zip
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:61)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:44)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DistributionFactory$ZippedDistribution.getToolingImplementationClasspath(DistributionFactory.java:108)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.loader.CachingToolingImplementationLoader.create(CachingToolingImplementationLoader.java:36)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.loader.SynchronizedToolingImplementationLoader.create(SynchronizedToolingImplementationLoader.java:40)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.LazyConsumerActionExecutor.onStartAction(LazyConsumerActionExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.LazyConsumerActionExecutor.run(LazyConsumerActionExecutor.java:81)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.run(ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.java:58)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.LoggingInitializerConsumerActionExecutor.run(LoggingInitializerConsumerActionExecutor.java:44)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:55)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Comment: Perhaps see the error log for details, and post them here.

Comment: Where do I find this "error-log"?

Comment: Window -> Show View -> Error Log

Comment: It is as the prophecy states!!.. Thanks :)

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser - Updated my question with the error log.

Answer (score 3):

My solution is that I went into the path:
**C:\Users\XXX .gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-3.3-all\55gk2rcmfc6p2dg9u9ohc3hw9**

Found that the **gradle-3.3-all.zip** was unfounded.I downloaded it by myself and droped it into the folder.

I clicked the synchronization button and waited for 5 minute,and clicked it again in Android Studio. It will freshen the file called **gradle-3.3-all.zip.part**.When the size of **gradle-3.3-all.zip.part** equal to the **gradle-3.3-all.zip**,it will decompress the zip automatically.

Of cause you can download the offline zip and decompress by yourself.
Then click the synchronization button again and fix the problem.

Igore my poor English.~

Comment: Just wanted to say that this happened to me on a Linux machine.  I think the automatic download was interrupted by a very flaky internet connection.   Downloading the file myself fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Might be something special in the build.gradle that leads to this problem. Can you raise a defect here https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse and attach the Gradle project you're trying to import into IDE using the Gradle Eclipse integration plug-in? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @aboyko , I've submitted the issue here: https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-3838

Answer (score 0):

As of I write this answer, in windows, Libgdx downloads install all the gradle files into C:\Users\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-2.2-all\3qtuormg932jiupng16e79muug\gradle-2.2. 
So I believe your gradle-2.2 may not have all of these files due to some reason. Please check it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue
I resolved it by changing the path of my "Gradle User Home". Directed it to the main **.gradle** path , for me it was **C:/Users/MyWork/.gradle**
And it worked like a charm

Answer (score 0):

In case of **REACT NATIVE**,
go to **android** directory by `cd android`
Then do gradle clean by  `gradle clean`
this will download the missing pieces.
It worked for me..